# The levenberg-marquardt method for solving non-linear equations

Tags: algorithm, math, julia, numerical-methods, levenberg-marquardt

I tried implement the levenberg-marquardt method for solving non-linear equations on Julia based on [Numerical Optimization using the 
Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm](http://mads.lanl.gov/presentations/Leif_LM_presentation_m.pdf) presentation. This my code:

```
function get_J(ArrOfFunc,X,delta)
  N = length(ArrOfFunc)
  J = zeros(Float64,N,N)
  for i = 1:N
    for j=1:N
      Temp = copy(X);
      Temp[j]=Temp[j]+delta;
      J[i,j] = (ArrOfFunc[i](Temp)-ArrOfFunc[i](X))/delta;
    end
  end
  return J
end

function get_resudial(ArrOfFunc,Arg)
  return  map((x)->x(Arg),ArrOfFunc)
end

function lm_solve(Funcs,Init)
  X = copy(Init)
  delta = 0.01;
  Lambda = 0.01;
  Factor = 2;
  J = get_J(Funcs,X,delta)
  R = get_resudial(Funcs,X)
  N = 5
  for t = 1:N

    G = J'*J+Lambda.*eye(length(X))
    dC = J'*R
    C = sum(R.*R)/2;
    Xnew = X-(inv(G)\dC);
    Rnew = get_resudial(Funcs,Xnew)
    Cnew =  sum(Rnew.*Rnew)/2;
    if ( Cnew < C)
      X = Xnew;
      R = Rnew;
      Lambda = Lambda/Factor;
      J = get_J(Funcs,X,delta)
    else
      Lambda = Lambda*Factor;
    end
    if(maximum(abs(Rnew)) < 0.001)
      return X
    end
  end
  return X
end

function test()
  ArrOfFunc = [
  (X)->X[1]+X[2]-2;
  (X)->X[1]-X[2]
  ];

  X = lm_solve(ArrOfFunc,Float64[3;3])
  println(X)
  return X
end
```

But from any starting point the step not accepted. What's I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't included the definition of the function `compute`, which makes it hard to test your code.

Comment: Should it not be either `inv(G)*dC` or `G\dC`, but not a mix of both? Preferably the second, since the solution of a linear system does not require the computation of the inverse matrix.

Comment: And what's the error message?

Comment: No specific problem is included which makes it hard to test. Even if one was included, this is better suited for CodeReview or Computational Science, not StackOverflow.

Comment: @DNF, sorry, I update the code.

Comment: @LutzL, thanks, you absolutely right. That's answer.

Comment: @LutzL: Please post that as an answer. CamFerry, welcome to Stack Overflow! For future questions, you should include the error message and try to narrow down the code to the minimal possible that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have at the moment no way to test this, but one line does not make sense mathematically:

In the computation of `Xnew` it should be either `inv(G)*dC` or `G\dC`, but not a mix of both. Preferably the second, since the solution of a linear system does not require the computation of the inverse matrix.

With this one wrong calculation at the center of the iteration, the trajectory of the computation is almost surely going astray.